# change url parameters changing id php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

How can you change the ID of the url and also change automatically the parameters like stackoverflow with php. example:

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/1000/example-entry
```

and if you manually change the "1000" to "1001" it also change the parameters at the end:

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/1001/another-example-entry
```

Is that made with php or redirect from the htaccess file?

Comment: which cms or framework you use? you can change by htaccess and php

Comment: I just use php, by far I made the code like this: 
example/article/26/article-name but if I change the 26 to another number it remains with the same name "article-name"... can you explain me how to redirect that? thanks

Comment: You can use a redirect from your PHP (when it sees that the requested url doesn't match concerning the article name) [back-end solution] or try Javascript's pushState to alter the location [front-end solution] (see jQuery Address plugin for that). The back-end solution is better, because it tells search engines to index the correct url.

Comment: Your question depends on how many url you have to change and on the logic of the URL modification: i.e., if you retrieve “another-example-entry” from db, you have to modify htaccess **and** process request by php